# Login using PHP and curl

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to check login details via php curl for `https://www.mercadolivre.com/jms/mlb/lgz/login?platform_id=mp&go=https://www.mercadopago.com/mlb/accountSummary`.

Here is my code

```
$username="****@outlook.com"; 
$password="******";
$callbackerror= "https://www.mercadolivre.com/jms/mlb/lgz/login";
$go = "https://www.mercadopago.com/mlb/accountSummary";
$platform_id = "mp";
$site_id = "mlb";
$loginType = "DEFAULT";
$dps = "554738efe4b0aed09e93f37d";
$parent_url = "";
$arfRedirUrl = "";
$confirm = "Entrar";


$url="https://www.mercadolivre.com/jms/mlb/lgz/login/authenticate"; 


$postdata = "user_id=$username&password=$password&callback_error=$callbackerror&go=$go&platform_id=$platform_id&site_id=$site_id&loginType=$loginType&dps=$dps&parent_url=$parent_url&arfRedirUrl=$arfRedirUrl&confirm=$confirm";
//$postdata = "user_id=".$username."&password=".$password."&dps=".$dps; 

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6"); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata); 

echo $result = curl_exec ($ch); 

curl_close($ch);
```

It returns empty. What I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Debug it with CURLOPT_VERBOSE first. Nobody here is going to figure out the form fields and requirements. It's up to you to be precise about that.

Comment: What if you set CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION to 1?